# Web API 2 - Unity IOC - Shared instance per request variable

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container, asp.net-web-api2

I am using web api with unity IOC.

web api client passes client-id in request header and based on this value dependencies are resolved to create a external dll's method instance.

creation of this instance take around 6-7 seconds which is creating performance issues in web api.

What I want is to prevent instance creation for call with same client-id in header.

This is how I have implemented till now:-

```
//========================== ArchiveFactory ==========================
        ArchiveFactory archiverFactory = (HttpRequest httpRequest) =>
        {
            container.RegisterType<IArchive, Archive>("Archive",
            new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(),
            new InjectionConstructor(
                new ResolvedParameter<IStoreClient>(),
                Helper.GetArchiveContext(httpRequest))
                );
            return container.Resolve<IArchive>("Archive");
        };
        container.RegisterInstance(archiverFactory);
```

To be specific in my requirement - I am calling amazon services to retrieve images and there is a corporate dll which invokes amazon.

Comment: Just to add more - I was thinking to have a static collection of instances. Later on I can check if instance is not available for a particular request, only then create new instance.

Comment: Hi container.Resolve<T> takes 6-7 seconds? Where is the most time spent in creating the instance?

Comment: constructor of T has to establish session with other services. Thats why I was thinking to construct T only once and use it for any further same kinda requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can use caching mechanism at the controller/API layer(e.g Strathweb.CacheOutput.WebApi2) and you can decorate the controller method like this below. It's can cache based on parameter so if request comes in with same parameter, it will return results from cache.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("")]
[CacheOutput(ServerTimeSpan = 60, ExcludeQueryStringFromCacheKey = true)]
public IHttpActionResult GetProducts(string clientId)
{
    var product = new List<Product>();
    return Ok(product);
}
```

Also, you might want to check the class constructor that you are trying to instantiate for issues that is taking it too slow. You may want to consider using lazy loading too if that will apply.